# Water pipes come through the floor too far from the wall for the vanity cutout

Tags: plumbing, walls, fitting, vanity

I'm fitting a vanity unit, but the water pipes and drain are too far from the wall (coming out of the ground). How do I move/adjust/fix the pipes, so the unit fits tight to the wall?

[image: vanity hitting plumbing but not the wall]

Comment: TBH, that is an odd vanity design with a gap in the floor panel to allow the plumbing to pass without having to cut the floor. OTOH, S-traps aren't allowed to be installed anymore, so it would work just fine for the now standard P-trap that would go into the wall instead of the floor. You might consider returning the vanity and getting one with a different floor and back design (like, one that _has_ a back).

Comment: "Flush" does not mean "tight". It means "on the same plane as".

Comment: @isherwood exactly?? the brackets should be flush to the wall, regardless of tightness (which refers to how much force is required (e.g. a press fit is tighter than a friction fit, which is tighter than slip fit) and only comes into play after something is touching)

Comment: Flush: `_ _ _` Tight: `_ [ ] _` Unless your cabinet is _in_ the wall, it can't be flush.

Answer (score 13):

Typically you cut a hole in the bottom of the vanity to accommodate the location of the pipes.

Comment: would it be possible cut the pipe then fit something like this https://www.screwfix.com/p/flomasta-plastic-push-fit-equal-90-elbow-15mm/371hy

so the pipe would fit flush to the wall ?

Comment: Generally not without violating the proper function of the drain pipe. If you want to actually move those pipes properly, you'll be ripping up the floor. Cutting the bottom of the vanity is a lot easier.

Comment: So after cutting I always seal the cut edge - even water from cleaning adds up.

Comment: Not all pipes are in the same position, so usually people cut hole/s to fit the pipes, rather than vanity makers making many holes to fit different pipe positions.

Comment: The part you have to cut here is essential to the strength of this cabinet.  If you fasten the side walls firmly to the rear wall using more than the single L bracket shown in your picture you ought to be fine.  Or buy a different vanity.  While you will need to cut the floor of anything you buy, you should not need to destroy a structural member like this.

Comment: Not clear that the vertical member needs to be cut - it eyeballs as going behind the pipes, just have to lift it into place, not slide it into place, with the hole in the shelf/bottom as per usual.

Comment: Cutting the horizontal beam will reduce the strength of the cabinet. If I recognize this particular vanity correctly, it is from IKEA and the horizontal beam is symmetrical. You can remove it from the cabinet, hang the cabinet, then feed the beam behind the pipe and install it with the lock-screws facing into the cabinet rather than to the wall.